# Error extract max value in a columns. VBA ( it is always return zero, why?)

Tags: excel, vba, max

Can anyone help to correct the code? It is always return zero, why? I want to compare the datas in columns H, and extract the value, store in offset(1,2). Please help to check my error, thanks very much

```
Dim Highest As Double

Highest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("H"))

 wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = Highest
```

Comment: Are your values text - this will give 0? if the standard `Max` function works, so should the VBA version.

Comment: Yes, my value is number. But the file is csv, any idea? Because of csv file?

Comment: I think is because of the text value since csv stores number in text, that's why i am getting zero, anyone has idea converting text to number in vba?

Comment: @user1828786 `CLng` for Long, `CDbl` for Double

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead - this is an array formula in `VBA` which converts text to numbers for the `Max` function.

```
Dim Highest As Double
Highest = Evaluate("Max(H:H*1)")
```